# How to handle a uint8_t array[8] in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, uint8t

I wasn't able to find a correct explanation on how to solve my problem.

I have a uint8_t array and I'm able to define it if I use this notation:

```
uint8_t array[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7A};
```

However, if I use this other notation:

```
uint8_t array[8];
array[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7A}
```

the compiler gives me an error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
```

How can I define my array later in my code after having initialized it?

**EDIT 1:**

I need to define the array inside the switch case like this:

```
uint8_t array[8];
    switch(relay_on){
    case 16: array[] = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7B}; // 
    break;
    }
```

and I need to use the array outside the switch.
The array is not available outside the switch if I declare it inside the switch case.

EDIT2: use with std::array

```
   std::array<uint8_t, 8> command1;
    std::array<uint8_t, 8> command2;

    switch(relay_on){
    case 16: command1 = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7B}; // switch on the relay 16
    break;
    }

    switch(relay_off){
    case 16: command2 = {0x58, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7A}; // switch off the relay 16
    break;
    }
int bytes_to_send1 = sizeof(command1);
    int bytes_to_send2 = sizeof(command2);
    int bytes_sent1 = 0;
    int bytes_sent2 = 0;

    do
    {
        n = send(sockfd, command1 + bytes_sent1, bytes_to_send1 - bytes_sent1, 0);
        if ( n < 0 )
        {
            cerr << "Error writing to socket!" << strerror(errno) << endl;
            close(sockfd);
        }
        bytes_sent1 += n;
    }
    while (bytes_sent1 < bytes_to_send1);
```

if I use the std::array notation, i get this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::array<unsigned char, 8>’ and ‘int’)
n = send(sockfd, command2 + bytes_sent2, bytes_to_send2 - bytes_sent2, 0);
```

Comment: You can't, at least  not without a loop.  Are you using C or C++?  C++ gives you `std::array` which is like an array, but "better" and supports these mechanics.

Comment: Good dup target but use `std::array` instead of `vector`.

Comment: I edited my first topic in order to add the switch case. I need to declare the array outside it and then to define it inside the switch case; then I need to use the array outside later in the code.

Comment: Use a `std::array`.  That would make your code look like `std::array<uint8_t, 8> command1;
    switch(relay_on){
    case 16: command1 = {0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7B}; // 
    break;
    }`

Comment: as an alternative, you can use `memcpy`

Comment: Thank you, @NathanOliver, it compiles but then it gives me an error as I reported in my first topic. The error is generated when I try to execute command1 + bytes_sent1

Comment: That's a completely different question, and you just need to read the chapter in your book about how to use `std::array`

Comment: I'm not a student so I have no book, I searched for std::array on google, but I found nothing related to my current problem.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet A good start is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array there you can look at this too https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data

Comment: @Amadeus should I use this notation: command1.data() + bytes_sent1 ? It gives me no error, but does this make sense?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet `send` is a C API, so, you need to provide data on that format. But now, as LightnessRacesInOrbit said, this is another question. For a more complete answer, you need to post a question